# How is it possible to write what looks like a read only property?

Tags: c#

Within the System.Exception base class there is the following property (as explained in the book pro c# 5.0):

`public virtual string Message { get; }`

This looks like a read-only property or a regular property without a body. Either way I cannot  replicate the above code myself.

EDIT:

If this describes a regular property the compiler complains that get has no body.

Comment: How are you viewing the code? If you are using a tool like DotPeek or Reflector, you don't always get back compilable source code.

Comment: Please include more details. The code you mentioned would perfectly work

Comment: @RohitKandhal No, it won't: you are not permitted to specify a read-only auto property. It is very likely the book is showing you the *metadata* for the property, not its implementation.

Comment: That's just not what the Message property looks like.  Use a decompiler or the Reference Source to see the real one.

Comment: That's the method signature - virtual getter, not the source implementation right (which likely returns the message created in the constructor)? Where does it say that's the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there is only a getter for `Message` is that it is not a auto property. Internally this is how Message is implmented (taken from the .NET reference source):

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public virtual string Message
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
  {
    if (this._message != null)
      return this._message;
    if (this._className == null)
      this._className = this.GetClassName();
    return Environment.GetRuntimeResourceString("Exception_WasThrown", new object[1]
    {
      (object) this._className
    });
  }
}
```

Internally Execption writes values to `_message`, the end user does not have read or write access to that member, but it provides a wrapper so a end user could get read only access to it.

Answer (score 5):

If you define a class like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

It will appear as get-only to the outside. `Exception` probably looks something like this:

```
public class Exception
{
    public Exception(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The book is not showing the *implementation* of the `Message` property, but rather its *metadata*. Trying to get such a line of code to compile will not work (as you discovered.)

To see what I mean, pop the following code into VS:

```
Exception e; string m = e.Message;
```

Put your cursor on the `Message` property, and hit F12: you will be taken to the line the book shows.